# Redirect old domain with http to new domain with https and www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my old domain `http://oldurl.edu/~oldname` to new domain `https://www.newname.org`. I tried creating the following .htaccess file in the root directory of the old domain

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newname.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

that returns 500 internal server error. How to make this work?

Comment: Check your Apache error.log to learn why 500 is coming.

Comment: Just to add, there is nothing syntactically wrong with what you have posted, so you will need to check your error log. It's possible that mod_rewrite is not enabled, or something...

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to access the error log file? The old domain is hosted in my university server (Apache 2.4.18 (Ubuntu)). I login there through a virtual workspace (vWorkspace from my personal computer). I only have access to the `public_html` directory where all my html files are in.

Answer (score 0):

instead of hammering your apache, try running it in an test environment. You can use - http://htaccess.mwl.be/ for testing your .htaccess.

See my working redirection example below.

```
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```